# Adding external libraries in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I am starting my adventure with Angular2 and I've read lots of tutorials, but there is one thing I am concern about. Lets say we have two views - one with report and one with upload image. 
**First view** will be handled by - let's say **'ReportComponent'** and on html template it will use 'Chart.js' library 
**Second view** will be handled by **'UploadMediaComponent'** and on html template it will use 'Dropzone.js' 
How to include this javascript libraries on html? In most tutorials I've read the only way to resolve it is to include **both** libraries in the index.html page (which is consistent with single page application pattern). But in the other hand - do we really need load hundreds of external libraries at once and beggining of loading the app even if we need to use it only in one view (one component)? Let's say I just need to use **'Dropzone.js'** on only one view, do I need to load it on every html view on client side?

Comment: I hope this will help you: https://medium.com/@s_eschweiler/using-external-libraries-with-angular-2-87e06db8e5d1#.pnt05l1nw

Comment: Dropzone in angular2: http://126kr.com/article/5q2i93rmste

Answer (score 1):

You could add file in your angular-cli.json configuration file.

Example :

```
 "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "../node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js",
    "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
    "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"    

    ]
```

directly add all JS build will generate script bundled version , Not needed any imports

Answer (score 0):

You could add file in your angular-cli.json configuration file.

Example :

```
"assets": [
    "path/Dropzone.js" ,
    "path/Chart.js"
  ],
```

Then directly include file to ReportComponent

```
<script src="/Chart.js"></script>
```

and UploadMediaComponent

```
<script src="/Dropzone.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `bower` or `npm` ? after you set it and install the libraries you need with `bower install package` it adds them to your html the libraries automatically.